# How to store an image in a JavaScript variable and render it to the web page?

Tags: javascript, image, rendering, client-side

I am trying to put a small `.jpg` file inside a JavaScript variable so that it can be rendered to the web page. I do **not** want to store the path to the image, but the actual image itself.

Even though I think this should be possible, I don't exactly know how to go about this. I would like all processing to be client-side.

Comment: COOL, didn't know this could even be done...

Answer (score 2):

This might help, [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

Comment: thanks, thats awesome, and exactly what I was looking for, more of a description would have been nice though.

Answer (score 0):

[Base-64 encoded images](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Always the contrarian:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'whatever.jpg';
```